# Returning a promise nested in forEach, in a .then function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, nested

I am struggling with returning a promise (or multiple promises) nested in a `forEach` function, which is nested in a `.then` function.

The second `.then` does not wait for the promise inside the first `.then` to complete and therefore does not return 'this.topics' (empty array instead) and logs `undefined` instead of data.

I think it is best to wrap your head around by looking at the code, so here it is:

```
getTopics() {

      this.$fireStore
        .collection("courses")
        .doc(this.$store.state.courses.currentlyPreviewing.cid)
        .collection("sections")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {

            snapshot.forEach(sec => {
              return this.$fireStore
                .collection("courses")
                .doc(this.$store.state.courses.currentlyPreviewing.cid)
                .collection("sections")
                .doc(sec.id)
                .collection("topics")
                .orderBy("order")
                .get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    this.topics.push({
                      data: doc.data(),
                      topic_id: doc.id,
                      sectionOfTopic_id: sec.id
                    });
                  });
                  console.log('First done!') // Only logged after data and this.topics
                });
            })
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data) // Logs undefined
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.topics)) // Logs empty array
          return this.topReady = true;
        });
```

Comment: you should use promise all for this case

Comment: `forEach` returns nothing, and that means it doesn't return a Promise either.  Depending on your requirements, you could use `map` inside a `Promise.all`, but this might cause thrashing depending on how many items your collection returns.  If your say already using a promise library like bluebird, it does have a promise based `map` that also has a concurrency option that make things like this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with a list or promises rather than a single promise, so take a look at using `Promise.all` instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

*The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.*

```
getTopics() {

  this.$fireStore
    .collection("courses")
    .doc(this.$store.state.courses.currentlyPreviewing.cid)
    .collection("sections")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const promises = snapshot.map(sec => {
          return this.$fireStore
            .collection("courses")
            .doc(this.$store.state.courses.currentlyPreviewing.cid)
            .collection("sections")
            .doc(sec.id)
            .collection("topics")
            .orderBy("order")
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.topics.push({
                  data: doc.data(),
                  topic_id: doc.id,
                  sectionOfTopic_id: sec.id
                });
              });
              console.log('First done!') // Only logged after data and this.topics
            });
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data) // Logs undefined
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.topics)) // Logs empty array
      return this.topReady = true;
    });
```

Comment: Think you narrowly beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the (very) quick reply, however I get an `snapshot.map is not a function` error when trying this solution.

Comment: @Aside what is snapshot? It has a `forEach` function but not a `.map` function? Can you do something to turn it into an array?

Comment: Snapshot is an object returned by Firebase after querying Firestore, however it contains the array `docs`, which is an array and contains everything I need. So doing `snapshot.docs.map` solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't really specify which bit is the promise -- `this.topics.push` ? `this.$fireStore...get()`?

I'm going to assume the latter one.

What you want to do is something more like this:

```
.then(snapshot => {
        var promises = snapshot.map(sec => {
          return this.$fireStore.
                       ...
                       .get()
          });
        return Promise.all(promises);
 });
```

When you do a `.map` and return a promise in the callback, you make an array of promises. `Promise.all` on an array of promises joins them into a single promise.